# SlideOverKit Menu as hamburger menu using FreshMVVM

Tags: xamarin.forms, uwp, freshmvvm

I am new in Xamarin and learning FreshMVVM.

Please can anyone guide me how can I dispaly [SlideOverKit](https://github.com/XAM-Consulting/SlideOverKit/): Right Menu as hamburger menu instead on button click using [FreshMVVM](https://github.com/rid00z/FreshMvvm) for MasterDetail form.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did u see the samples in here https://github.com/XAM-Consulting/SlideOverKit/tree/master/SlideOverKitMoreSamples?

Comment: Ok, I will check and reply. Thanks for your quick reply

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure abut FreshMVVM but all you have to do is to add a ToolbarItem which has an icon of Menu. Than, bind the click command to show the slideOverKit menu.

```
<ContentPage>
    <ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
        <ToolbarItem Name="Cart" Command="{Binding GoToCartCommand}" Icon="Icons/cart.png"></ToolbarItem>
    </ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <!-- your content goes here -->
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```